# pyqt5でQScrollAreaを使ったときの初期サイズを設定したい

Tags: python, pyqt5

pyqt5のQScrollAreaでウィンドウの中にスクロールされるエリアを作ろうと思います。その際、ウィンドウを立ち上げた際のスクロールエリアの初期サイズが小さいです。setFixedSizeやsetMinimumSizeを使えばサイズを指定できますが、サイズの調整に縛りが出来てしまいます。

スクロールエリアの初期サイズを指定させるにはどのようにすればよいのでしょうか。

---

**表示されるGUI**
[image: 画像]

**ソースコード**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui,QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        val=30
        self.title = "PyQt5 Scroll Bar"

        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("icon.png"))
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        
        self.figure1 = plt.figure(figsize=(4,4), dpi=100)   
        self.canvas1 = FigureCanvas(self.figure1)
        self.axes1 = Axes3D(self.figure1)
        self.canvas1.setMinimumSize(400,400)

        self.figure2 = plt.figure(figsize=(4,4), dpi=100) 
        self.canvas2 = FigureCanvas(self.figure2)
        self.axes2 = Axes3D(self.figure2)
        self.canvas2.setMinimumSize(400,400)
        
        self.figure3 = plt.figure(figsize=(4,4), dpi=100) 
        self.canvas3 = FigureCanvas(self.figure3)
        self.axes3 = Axes3D(self.figure3)
        self.canvas3.setMinimumSize(400,400)
        
        self.figure4 = plt.figure(figsize=(4,4), dpi=100)
        self.axes4 = self.figure4.add_subplot(111)
        self.canvas4 = FigureCanvas(self.figure4)
        self.axes4.set_aspect("equal")
        self.canvas4.setMinimumSize(400,400)

        self.figure5 = plt.figure(figsize=(4,4), dpi=100)
        self.axes5 = self.figure5.add_subplot(111)
        self.canvas5 = FigureCanvas(self.figure5)
        self.axes5.set_aspect("equal")
        self.canvas5.setMinimumSize(400,400)
        
        self.figure6 = plt.figure(figsize=(4,4), dpi=100)
        self.axes6 = self.figure6.add_subplot(111)
        self.canvas6 = FigureCanvas(self.figure6)
        self.axes6.set_aspect("equal")
        self.canvas6.setMinimumSize(400,400)
        
        self.figure7 = plt.figure(figsize=(4,4), dpi=100)
        self.axes7 = self.figure7.add_subplot(111,polar=True)
        self.canvas7 = FigureCanvas(self.figure7)
        self.axes7.set_aspect("equal")
        self.canvas7.setMinimumSize(400,400)

        self.figure8 = plt.figure(figsize=(4,4), dpi=100)
        self.axes8 = self.figure8.add_subplot(111,polar=True)
        self.canvas8 = FigureCanvas(self.figure8)
        self.axes8.set_aspect("equal")
        self.canvas8.setMinimumSize(400,400)
        
        self.figure9 = plt.figure(figsize=(4,4), dpi=100)
        self.axes9 = self.figure9.add_subplot(111,polar=True)
        self.canvas9 = FigureCanvas(self.figure9)
        self.axes9.set_aspect("equal")
        self.canvas9.setMinimumSize(400,400)
        
        layout=QGridLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas1,0,0)
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas2,0,1)
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas3,0,2)
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas4,1,0)
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas5,1,1)
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas6,1,2)
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas7,2,0)
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas8,2,1)
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas9,2,2)
        
        groupBox = QGroupBox("Canvas")
        groupBox.setLayout(layout)

        scroll = QScrollArea()
        scroll.setWidget(groupBox)
        scroll.setWidgetResizable(True)
        
        
        layout2 = QVBoxLayout()
        layout2.addWidget(scroll)

        self.setLayout(layout2)
        self.show()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = Window()
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())  # only need one app, one running event loop
    #app.exec_()
```

Comment: スクロールアリアの初期サイズ、というのは、どういう意味でしょうか? (スクロールエリア内のウィジェットサイズをうまく指定したい、という意味?)

Comment: 分かりにくくてすみません。スクロールエリア内のウィジットサイズではなく、スクロールエリアそれ自体の領域の大きさです。例示したソースコードではscrollの大きさです。コードを実行し、ウィンドウが開いた際のスクロールエリア領域の大きさを指定したいです。

Comment: 見る限り、レイアウトも指定されていてウインドウサイズにあったサイズでスクロールエリアは表示されるように見えますが、ウインドウとスクロールエリア領域の間の隙間を詰めたい、という意味でしょうか?

Comment: 現在スクロールエリア内にはウィジットとして9つのグラフが入っていますが、ウィンドウ立ち上げ時は見ての通り1個半が映る程度の大きさのスクロールエリアが表示されます。このスクロールエリアを例えば、グラフが6個程度入るようなサイズで最初から起動されれば、と思っています。やっぱりウィンドウサイズ自体をresizeするのが一番自然でしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

コメントなどから、`QScrollArea`内のウィジェットサイズに比例してウインドウ(質問文の「表示されるGUI」)の初期サイズを変更する方法を知りたい、と想定し、回答します。

実装されている「`Window`」クラスに「`sizeHint`」メソッドを追加すると初期サイズの制御ができるので、`QScrollArea`内のウィジェットサイズに応じた値を返すようにするとよいと思います。
(`sizeHint`メソッドは`QWidget`のメソッドなので、正しくはオーバーライドです)

実験した限りだと、`self.setLayout(layout2)`の実行時点でウィジェットのサイズは算出できているようなので、`scroll`変数をメンバに加え、次のように`sizeHint`を実装するとウィジェットサイズの70%くらいのサイズでウインドウが表示されると思います。(つまり全体の70%が表示されている)

```py
    def sizeHint():
        return self.scroll.widget().size() * 0.7
```

いかがでしょうか?

＃あまりきれいではありませんが、明示的に`resize`するよりは「それらしい」かと思います。

Comment: おおお！これです！わかりにくい質問でしたが、丁寧に付き合っていただき有難うございました。